# Send Button Action to Custom Class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hello i can't make this code work. I am receiving this error "unrecognised selector sent to instance".

I have tried to put the @Objc in front of method signature but still wasn't working

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public class BasePopup: NSObject{

     var backgroundView:UIView!

     public init() {
         super.init()

         ....
          //Previous elements
         ....

         btnClose.addTarget(self, 
                            action: "hidePopup:",
                            forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
     }

     func hidePopup(sender:AnyObject){
        backgroundView.hidden = true
     }
}
```

Comment: Try ' hidePopup : ' (with the space)

Comment: Didn't worked. I use the same code snippet inside my ViewController classes and works perfectly. Don't know why is doesn't here